# Typescript merging ES6 modules into library with consistent typings

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

The problem I am facing is the following:

I want to merge multiple modules into one library. The following code shows my approach:

> ./Imports/index.ts ::: The library

```js
import * as _A from './ModuleA';
export const A = _A;

import * as _B from './ModuleB';
export const B = _B;
```

> ./Imports/ModuleA.ts ::: Module A

```js
export class foo {};
```

> ./Imports/ModuleB.ts ::: Module B

```js
export const bar = 10;
```

> ./main.ts ::: Using the library

```js
import * as Import from './Imports/index'

// this works fine
var bar = Import.B.bar;
var fooInstance = new Import.A.foo();

// but cant use as types
var bar2: typeof Import.B.bar;
var fooInstance2: new Import.A.foo;
```

The Problem is, although I can use the library, I can not use the members of the Modules as types.

---

In order to use them i have to export the module member directly, like so:

> ./Imports/index2.ts ::: Alternate library

```js
export * from './ModuleA';
export * from './ModuleB';
```

> ./main.ts ::: Using the library

```js
import * as Import from './Imports/index2'

// this works fine
var bar = Import.bar;
var fooInstance = new Import.foo();

// this works fine
var bar2: typeof Import.bar;
var fooInstance2: new Import.foo;
```

The problem here is that i can get name collisions and it gets kind of unorganized pretty fast.

I guess the problem is how ES6 modules work. Has anyone a good advise to fix or bypass this problem?